# Is NP a subring of the 2-adic integers?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, p-vs-np, algebra

Let me take the set $A = \{1, 2\}$ as the alphabet. By the bijective binary numeral system, $A^*$ has one-to-one correspondence to the set of nonnegative integers $\mathbb{N}$. As such, each language $L \subset A^*$ corresponds to a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Now consider the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, and treat its elements as languages. Considering each language as a decision problem over $\mathbb{N}$, we now have the complexity class $\mathsf{ALL}$.

Now note that each element $L$ of the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ can be treated as a 2-adic integer (denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_2$) by "setting" the $n$-th bit for each $n \in L$. For examples:

- When $L = \{0, 2, 3\}$, the corresponding 2-adic integer is $13$.
- When $L = \mathbb{N}$, the corresponding 2-adic integer is $-1$.
- When $L = \{2n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, the corresponding 2-adic integer is $-\frac{1}{3}$.
- Of course, there are $\beth_1$ many 2-adic integers and an $L$ corresponding to each of them.

We now have a ring structure for $\mathsf{ALL}$. But what about smaller complexity classes?

I focused on the operators of 2-adic integers. Note that the addition for 2-adic integers is defined as the schoolbook addition; bitwise add-with-carry. This operator can be lazily evaluated to yield the linear time complexity. To elaborate, suppose the inputs $L_1$ and $L_2$ take $O(f(n))$ time to have their $n$-th bit evaluated. Provided that $O(n) \subset O(f(n))$, $L_1 + L_2$ should also take $O(f(n))$ time to have its  $n$-th bit evaluated. So the following complexity classes are closed under addition:

- $\mathsf{P}$
- $\mathsf{EXPTIME}$
- $\mathsf{R}$

Likewise for the multiplication. Since multiplication for 2-adic integers is defined as the schoolbook multiplication, which takes quadratic time, by a similar argument as above, the complexity classes above are also closed under multiplication.

But what about $\mathsf{NP}$? That is, provided that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are in $\mathsf{NP}$, are $L_1 + L_2$ and $L_1 \times L_2$ also in $\mathsf{NP}$? I tried imagining the numbers involved as prover-verifier pairs, and this is how the proof went:

> We must build a prover-verifier pair for $L_1 + L_2$ when prover-verifier pairs for $L_1$ and $L_2$ are provided. This is how the verifier for $L_1 + L_2$ will work then fed a word $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
>
> 1. The verifier for $L_1 + L_2$ sends the word $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ to the prover-verifier pair for $L_1$, and simultaneously, to the prover-verifier pair for $L_2$ also.
> 2. Then the prover-verifier pair for $L_1$ verifies whether $n \in L_1$, likewise for that for $L_2$. This takes polynomial time. Then, this verification result is sent back to the verifier for $L_1 + L_2$; $1$ for acceptation and $0$ for rejection.
> 3. The step #1-#2 is repeated, except that the verifier for $L_1 + L_2$ sends the word $1 \in \mathbb{N}$, $2 \in \mathbb{N}$ and so on until the word $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is sent. This takes polynomial time.
> 4. Now the verifier for $L_1 + L_2$ has gathered two length-$n$ binary strings; add them by schoolbook addition, and read the $n$-th bit. Now accept if the bit is $1$, and reject if the bit is $0$.

Likewise for multiplication. But I'm still unsure because this whole system of machines isn't a single prover-verifier pair. I don't know whether the prover-verifier pairs for $L_1$ and $L_2$ can be "packaged" into one prover. Is this really a valid proof?

Comment: Note that if it takes $\Omega(n)$ time to evaluate the n-th bit than this is inherently exponential (since numbers take logarithmic length to represent), so it just isn't relevant for P and NP.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it should be possible, because you might need to prove a bit is 0 which you can't assuming NP≠coNP